# How to delete a VA Smalltalk edition of method

Tags: smalltalk

I am using VA Smalltalk and I want to understand how to delete particular editions of any method which I have created by mistake, they are not duplicate methods but are unwanted as well. please let me know if there is a way to do so, I dont want to delete all the previous edition only few selected editions

Comment: If you modified a method and now want to discard the modified version, find in the method history the previous version and reinstall it. If you instead added a new method that you no longer want, just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no possibility to delete method editions in VAST. You can purge application editions to keep the history "clean", but on the method level the editions you've saved will still remain.